# Heinrich Hertz on Mathematical Equations

Tags: reference-request, physics, mathematical-physics

What is the quote from Heinrich Hertz on how he could never exhaust the meaning behind a mathematical equation? (It's not mentioned in the [Hertz quotations here](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Heinrich_Hertz).)

Comment: Is it this one? Not terribly similar to what you are asking!  "One cannot escape the feeling that these mathematical formulas have an independent existence and an intelligence of their own, that they are wiser than we are, wiser even than their discoverers ... "

Comment: @Paul: Yes, I think that might be it! Where did Hertz say that? thanks

Comment: No idea where he said it but I found it here http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/ and search for Hertz. Handy website, full of things you can throw into a class.

Comment: @Paul: Thanks. I love the MacTutor Archive.

Answer (score 0):

In the article linked below, you can find the history of the quote and the original quote in German, which, translated in English, indeed begins with: “We cannot study this wonderful theory without at times feeling…” in reference to Maxwell’s theory of electromagnetism. Hertz said that at a conference in Heidelberg, 1889.

[Heinrich Hertz on the wisdom of equations](https://bit.ly/HertzWisdomEquations)